# chrome extension search_url_post_params search provider override

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, flask

I'm currently overriding chrome's default search provider with the "search_url" property under the manifest's "chrome_settings_overrides". I'm overriding this search url with a url that will redirect to my own Flask server. I now want to include post parameters during this redirection and read them on the server.

[Google's docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override) outlines the "search_url_post_params" but without much explanation as to how this property is used in the extension's search request let alone Flask's "request" object on the server-side.

How do I include post parameters in the default search url of a chrome extension?
Here is the override settings in my manifest.json

```
"chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "is_default": true,
      "encoding": "UTF-8",
      "keyword": "My Extension",
      "name": "My Extension",
      "favicon_url": "https://myflaskapp.com",
      "search_url": "http://myflaskapp.com/search?query={searchTerms}",
      "suggest_url": "https://myflaskapp.com/suggest?prefix={searchTerms}",
      "search_url_post_params": "testparam=extension"
    }
  }
```

I want to read the post param on my Flask server in some way like this:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST']
def search():
    testparam = request.form['testparam']
```

Comment: See [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](//stackoverflow.com/a/14551320): `"foo=bar&herp=derp"`

Comment: I understand how post parameters are formatted, but the request to `http://myflaskapp.com/search?query={searchTerms}` are only ever GET requests, so I don't think the `"search_url_post_params"` are even being sent with the request in the first place

Answer (score 2):

[`search_url_post_params` doesn't actually work](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=268698). And it doesn't look like anyone is working on it.